# Python for loop: Proper implementation of multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

The following for loop is part of a iterative simulation process and is the main bottleneck regarding computational time:

```py
import numpy as np

class Simulation(object):

    def __init__(self,n_int):
        self.n_int = n_int

    def loop(self):

        for itr in range(self.n_int):        
            #some preceeding code which updates rows_list and diff with every itr
            cols_red_list = []
            rows_list = list(range(2500)) #row idx for diff where negative element is known to appear
            diff = np.random.uniform(-1.323, 3.780, (2500, 300)) #np.random.uniform is just used as toy example 

            for row in rows_list:
                col =  next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(diff[row,:]) if val < 0)
                cols_red_list.append(col)
            # some subsequent code which uses the cols_red_list data    
sim1 = Simulation(n_int=10)
sim1.loop()
```

Hence, I tried to parallelize it by using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#) package in hope to reduce computation time:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import  Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

def crossings(row, diff):
    return next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(diff[row,:]) if val < 0)

class Simulation(object): 
    def __init__(self,n_int):
        self.n_int = n_int

    def loop(self):        
        for itr in range(self.n_int): 
            #some preceeding code which updates rows_list and diff with every
            rows_list = list(range(2500))
            diff = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2500, 300))

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                num_of_workers = cpu_count()
                print('number of CPUs : ', num_of_workers)
                pool = Pool(num_of_workers)
                cols_red_list = pool.map(partial(crossings,diff = diff), rows_list)
                pool.close()
                print(len(cols_red_list))
            # some subsequent code which uses the cols_red_list data 

sim1 = Simulation(n_int=10)
sim1.loop()
```

Unfortunately, the parallelization turns out to be much slower compared to the sequential piece of code. 
Hence my question: Did I use the multiprocessing package properly in that particular example? Are there alternative ways to parallelize the above mentioned for loop ?

Comment: Submitting 2500 jobs to the pool is a bad strategy if each job is very quick. Rather split the list into `num_of_workers` equally sized batches so that you only submit `num_of_workers` jobs.

Comment: @AlexHall I believe they are doing that with 10 different pools of `n_workers`, each of which is handling 2500 jobs.

Comment: That if __name__ block inside the for loop, Is that an indentation problem?

Comment: There's a few things going on:

1. pool is created 10 times, this basically adds pool creation overhead to the benchmark.
2. a list with 2500 elements is pickled and partially sent to workers.
3. diff is apparently a huge matrix that gets pickled as well?

Even when moving pool.map up a level (so 10 iterations of the sequential version, which all create their own data) and upping `2500` to `25000`, the multiprocessing version is only slightly faster than the sequential one, most likely to the matrix generation. Is there a way to prevent pickling of the pre-generated data?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: As you're trying to reduce the runtime of your code *through parallelisation*, this doesn't strictly answer your question but it might still be a good learning opportunity.

> As a golden rule, before moving to multiprocessing to improve
>   performance (execution time), one should first optimise the
>   single-threaded case.

Your

```
rows_list = list(range(2500))
```

Generates the numbers `0` to `2499` (that's the `range`) and stores them in memory (`list`), which requires time to do the allocation of the required memory and the actual write. You then only use these predictable values once each, by reading them from memory (which also takes time), in a predictable order:

```
for row in rows_list:
```

This is particularly relevant to the runtime of your `loop` function as you do it repeatedly (`for itr in range(n_int):`).

Instead, consider generating the number only when you need it, without an intermediate store (which conceptually removes any need to access RAM):

```
for row in range(2500):
```

Secondly, on top of sharing the same issue (unnecessary accesses to memory), the following:

```
diff = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2500, 300))
# ...
    col =  next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(diff[row,:]) if val < 0)
```

seems to me to be optimisable at the level of math (or logic).

What you're trying to do is get a random variable (that `col` index) by defining it as "the first time I encounter a random variable in [-1;1] that is lower than 0". But notice that figuring out if a random variable with a uniform distribution over [-α;α] is negative, is the same as having a random variable over {0,1} (*i.e.* a `bool`).

Therefore, you're now working with `bool`s instead of `float`s and you don't even have to do the comparison (`val < 0`) as you already have a bool. This potentially makes the code much faster. Using the same idea as for `rows_list`, you can generate that `bool` only when you need it; testing it until it is `True` (or `False`, choose one, it doesn't matter obviously). By doing so, you only generate as many random `bool`s as you need, not more and not less (BTW, what happens in your code if all 300 elements in the row are negative? ;) ):

```
for _ in range(n_int):
    cols_red_list = []
    for row in range(2500):
        col = next(i for i in itertools.count() if random.getrandbits(1))
        cols_red_list.append(col)
```

or, with list comprehension:

```
cols_red_list = [next(i for i in count() if getrandbits(1))
                 for _ in range(2500)]
```

I'm sure that, through proper statistical analysis, you even can express that `col` random variable as a non-uniform variable over [0;`limit`[, allowing you to compute it much faster.

Please test the performance of an "optimized" version of your single-threaded implementation first. If the runtime is still not acceptable, you should then look into multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing` uses system processes (not threads!) for parallelization, which require expensive IPC (inter-process communication) to share data.

This bites you in two spots:

- `diff = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2500, 300))` creates a large matrix which is expensive to pickle/copy to another process
- `rows_list = list(range(2500))` creates a smaller list, but the same applies here.

To avoid this expensive IPC, you have one and a half choices:

- If on a POSIX-compliant system, initialize your variables on the module level, that way each process gets a quick-and-dirty copy of the required data. This is not scalable as it requires POSIX, weird architecture (you probably don't want to put everything on the module level), and doesn't support sharing changes to that data.
- Use shared memory. This only supports mostly primitive data types, but `mp.Array` should cover your needs.

The second problem is that setting up a pool is expensive, as `num_cpu` processes need to be started. Your workload is small enough to be negligible compared to this overhead. A good practice is to only create one pool and reuse it.

Here is a quick-and-dirty example of the POSIX only solution:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import  Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

n_int = 10

rows_list = np.array(range(2500))
diff = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2500, 300))


def crossings(row, diff):
    return next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(diff[row,:]) if val < 0)

def workload(_):
    cols_red_list = [crossings(row, diff) for row in rows_list]
    print(len(cols_red_list))


class Simulation(object):

    def loop(self):
        num_of_workers = cpu_count() 
        with Pool(num_of_workers) as pool:
            pool.map(workload, range(10))
        pool.close()

sim1 = Simulation()
sim1.loop()
```

For me (and my two cores) this is roughly twice as fast as the sequential version.

*Update with shared memory:*

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import  Pool, cpu_count, Array
from functools import partial

n_int = 10

ROW_COUNT = 2500


### WORKER

diff = None
result = None

def init_worker(*args):
    global diff, result
    (diff, result) = args


def crossings(i):
    result[i] = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(diff[i*300:(i+1)*300]) if val < 0)


### MAIN

class Simulation():
    def loop(self):
        num_of_workers = cpu_count() 

        diff = Array('d', range(ROW_COUNT*300), lock=False)
        result = Array('i', ROW_COUNT, lock=False)
        # Shared memory needs to be passed when workers are spawned
        pool = Pool(num_of_workers, initializer=init_worker, initargs=(diff, result))

        for i in range(n_int):

            # SLOW, I assume you use a different source of values anyway.
            diff[:] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, ROW_COUNT*300)

            pool.map(partial(crossings), range(ROW_COUNT))
            print(len(result))
        pool.close()


sim1 = Simulation()
sim1.loop()
```

A few notes:

- Shared memory needs to be set up at worker creation, so it's global anyway.
- This still isn't faster than the sequential version, but that's mainly due to random.uniform needing to be copied entirely into shared memory. I assume that are just values for testing, and in reality you'd fill it differently anyway.
- I only pass indices to the worker, and use them to read and write values to the shared memory.

Comment: Probably my given example was not specific enough - I updated it. In your POSIX only solution, looping with `n_int` interations is not possible anymore. However, I need this loop in order to execute some preceeding sequential  and subsequent sequential code. The preceeding code is actually generating the `diff` array and also `rows_list`.  I just used `np.random.uniform()' and `range()` for illustrativ purposes.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an example using shared memory with mp.Array() . I tried to look it up in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) of multiprocessing but its mainly explained using Process() and not Pool().

Comment: Oh well, I just tried it with multiprocessing.Manager.Array (as multiprocessing.Array can't be passed to pool that easily), but it looks like splitting the 2500 rows onto the workers is another thing that takes very long. Honestly I think python parallelization is borderline useless and you'd be better off looking into Go or D for easy alternatives (there's a reason all those science libraries have backends in C/C++), but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Updated it with shared memory, your mileage may vary.